# react setstate not rendering until callback finishes

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to change button to saving state while I run code to get information.

I have 
`this.setState({ saving: true }, () => this.save(event) })`

In `this.save` I have a rest call.  I can see from the log that the state is updated but visually on the site the button does not go into the spinning circle like it should with that updated value.

Is there a way to force update rendering before running the callback function or a better method to set a button to saving while I do a remote call that could take a little bit of time?

Comment: why don't you simply call `this.save(event)` _after_ the `this.setstate()` call?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @matejcik Your suggestion will guarantee that state will change **after** the call to `this.save()` because `setState()` is asynchronous.

Comment: And shouldn't your code be `this.setState()` instead of `this.setstate()`?

Comment: Why you don't call `this.setState({ saving: true });` inside your `this.save()`? ex: `this.save = () => { this.setState({saving: true}); /*your SAVING code*/  this.setState({saving: false});}

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to force this. Change your state in parallel to the actual saving:

```
<button onClick={() => this.save()}>save</button>
```

paired with:

```
save() {
  this.setState({ saving: true });
  remoteAPI.save({ 
    data: this.getSaveData(),
    credentials: this.getCredentials()
    ...
  }, response => {
    this.setState({ saving: false });
    if(response.error) {
      // ohnoes!
    } else {
      // nice.
    }
  });
}
```